# how to show minus currency in brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have variable which is negative numbers after $ sign (actually it shows currency with currency sign). Please tell me how to show minus currency in brackets with currency sign. I mean to say how to change var val=($125,220,328.00)

My code is looks like this

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

function netAmount(){
    var net_amount =0;
    $('#productList tr:gt(1)').each(function() {
        var row_index= $(this).index();
        var qty= $('#productList tr:eq('+row_index+') td input[name="quantity"]').val().replace( /[^0-9\.]/g, '' );
        var price= $('#productList tr:eq('+row_index+') td input[name="purchase_price"]').val().replace( /[^0-9\.]/g, '' );
        net_amount+= +(parseFloat(qty*price).toFixed(2));
        $('input[name="net_ammount"]').val('$'+ addCommas(parseFloat(net_amount).toFixed(2)));

    });
}
```

Now i want if net_amount is looks like -123225.32 then it show in input[name="net_ammount"] as ($123,225.32)

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp doesn't match the minus sign, therefore it is not added in the replacement. Change the regexp to this:

```
var rgx = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/;
```

Comment: @h2ooooooo The $ is not part of the number. addCommas is used on a floating point value.

Comment: Not completely correct (it's used on a `float.toFixed()`, so it's a string), but you're right - there won't be a currency symbol.